# Find the CDF of a function given its PDF

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, density-function

The probability density function of the random variable X is as follows

$f_{X}(x) = \begin{cases}
1/4,  & \text{if 0 < x < 1} \\
1/4, & \text{if 2 < x < 4}\\
1/4, & \text{if 6 < x < 7}\\
0, & \text{elsewhere}\\
\end{cases}$

I know that

- I can find the cumulative distribution function by integrating the probability density function from $-\infty$ to $x$,
- and   also that for values of $x$ less than or equal to $0$, the CDF will be $0$,
- and for values of $x$ greater than or equal to $7$, the CDF will be $1$.

> I know how to integrate each piece, however how do I fill in the gaps
>      between the pieces, such as $1 < x < 2$?

I thought that since it is cumulative, this part would just be the same as the part before it
   since it doesn't add anymore probability, however if I were to let,
   for example, $F_x(x)$ = $\frac{1}{4}x$ for 0 < x < 2, then if I were
   to differentiate this to get back to the PDF, it isn't going to
   result in the correct domain.

Comment: For the "gaps" you use the "elsewhere" part of the density function.

Comment: @Jack if I use this part though, integrating 0dt will just give me zero. However, since it is cumulative, it should not be zero in these gap spots, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a typical example of what happens in a gap, look at $3/2$, which is in the first gap. The CDF value at $3/2$ is
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{3/2}f_X(x)\,dx=
\int_{-\infty}^00\,dx+\int_0^1\frac14\,dx+\int_1^{3/2}0\,dx=
0+\frac14+0=\frac14.
$$
The rest of $F_X$ can be computed the same way (though the integral splits into more pieces when you go to later intervals).

Answer (score 2):

$F_{X}(x) = \begin{cases}
0, & x \leq 0 \\
x/4,  & \text{if 0 < x } \leq 1\\
1/4, & \text{if 1< x }\leq 2\\
1/4+(x-2)/4, & \text{if 2 < x } \leq 4\\
3/4, & \text{if 4 < x } \leq 6\\
3/4+(x-6)/4, & \text{if 6 < x }\leq 7\\
1, & \text{elsewhere}\\
\end{cases}$

The CDF stays constant when the density is zero.